# how to make this call from shopify ? (GET/POST) python

Tags: python, api, shopify

I have to make this call with Standard shopify API (python)

```
https://store.myshopify.com/admin/shop.json
```

what i am getting is :

```
ipdb> shopify.Shop.current()
shop(2330215)
```

but :

```
ipdb> shopify.Shop.get(2330215)
*** ResourceNotFound: Not Found:https://store.myshopify.com/admin/shops/2330215.xml
```

ipdb>

what is the right way to make such call .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no `/admin/shops` (plural) API path, *at all*.

You use the API **per shop**, the `shop_url` parameter gives you access to a specific shop and then you cannot access other shops nor do you need to use `shopify.Shop.get()`.

The Python library uses a generic base class for all resource types, and that is where the `.get()` method comes from, but that method *has no meaning* for shops.

The `shopify.Shop.current()` returns the one shop resource that you need to care about. It has an `.attributes` attribute that holds all the data returned by the Shopify API; keys in that mapping also work as attributes on the main resource object:

```
shop = shopify.Shop.current()
print shop.attributes.keys()
print shop.name
```